# Value of type 'StorageReference' has no member 'child'

Tags: firebase, swift4

I get always this porblem after opening the project. what could i do ?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class FIRImage
{
    var image: UIImage
    var downloadURI: String?
    var ref: StorageReference!

    init(image: UIImage) {
        self.image = image
    }
}

extension FIRImage
{
    func saveProfileImage(_ userUID: String, _ completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void)
    {
        let resizedImage = image.resized()
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resizedImage, 0.9)

        ref = StorageReference.profileImages.reference().child(userUID)
        downloadURI = ref.debugDescription

        ref.put(imageData!, metadata: nil) { (metaData, error) in
            completion(error)
        }
    }

    func save(_ uid: String, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void)
    {
        let resizedImage = image.resized()
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resizedImage, 0.9)

        ref = StorageReference.images.reference().child(uid)
        downloadURI = ref.debugDescription

        refput(imageData!, metadata: nil) { (metaData, error) in
            completion(error)
        }
    }
}


extension FIRImage
{
    class func downloadProfileImage(_ uid: String, completion: @escaping (UIImage?, Error?) -> Void)
    {
        StorageReference.profileImages.reference().child(uid).data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (imageData, error) in
            if error == nil && imageData != nil {
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                completion(image, error)
            } else {
                completion(nil, error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow :). Your question is very difficult to read due to an incorrect formatting. Can you please fix this? Please take a look here: [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for detailled instructions.

Comment: Is still not working. After a pod update the file isnt working anymore. Have only this two errors: Value of type 'StorageReference' has no member 'child' and Value of type 'StorageReference?' has no member 'put'. I tried with putting putData instead of only put but still these errors, dont know what to do...